# Kotlin android apk

Tags: android, kotlin

Создал приложение на андроид, использовал android 4.4 kitKat, api 19
Установил на свой телефон, на нем версия андроид 6.0, но приложение не запускается, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в чем угодно. Нужны логи ошибок или другие данные

Comment: зачем устанавливать? запускай на телефоне прямо из отладчика

Comment: Попробуйте для начала запустить на эмуляторе с Андроид 6.